# display a point based on where a mouse click has occured tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So basically i have been asked to create a naughts and crosses game interface however i cant seem to figure out how to display a point based on a mouse click. So far, i can retrieve x and y coordinated based on where the moused has been clicked but i cant display a point at this position. My code is as follows, thanks in advance:

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
         Tk.__init__(self)

         self.mygui()



def mygui(self):
    self.title('Naughts and Crosses')
    self.geometry('600x400+700+300')

    self.bind('<Button-1>', self.get_location)

    #creating a naughts and crosses board

    canvas = Canvas(self, width=1000, height=1000)

    canvas.create_line(100, 140, 500, 140)
    canvas.create_line(100, 250,500, 250)

    canvas.create_line(220, 50, 220, 350)
    canvas.create_line(370, 50, 370, 350)

    canvas.pack()

def get_location(self, eventorigin):
    x = eventorigin.x
    y = eventorigin.y
    # x and y will return three figure coordinates, this is where i am 
    stuck.

Window().mainloop()
```

Comment: I imagine you want a function that can draw a cross on the canvas or some other pattern. I answer a question some time ago that did something similar I will see if I can find it.

Comment: OK thanks i appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is actually fairly straight forward. I'm going to layout the steps to get you started for the first box and then the rest should be easy from there.

I started with the top left and middle boxes and used the line coordinates you used to get the top right and bottom left points of each box. I then check if the mouse click coordinates lie between those points and thus are within the given box.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
         Tk.__init__(self)

         self.mygui()

         # Define the bounds of each box based on the lines drawn in mygui
         self.topleft = [(100,220), (50, 140)]
         self.topmiddle = [(220, 370), (50, 140)]

    def mygui(self):
        self.title('Naughts and Crosses')
        self.geometry('600x400+700+300')

        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.get_location)

        #creating a naughts and crosses board

        canvas = Canvas(self, width=1000, height=1000)

        canvas.create_line(100, 140, 500, 140)
        canvas.create_line(100, 250,500, 250)

        canvas.create_line(220, 50, 220, 350)
        canvas.create_line(370, 50, 370, 350)

        canvas.pack()

    def get_location(self, eventorigin):
        x = eventorigin.x
        y = eventorigin.y
        # x and y will return three figure coordinates, this is where i am stuck.

        print(x, y)
        print(self.topleft)
        print(self.topmiddle)

        # Check if the mouse click is in the top left box
        if(x > self.topleft[0][0] and x < self.topleft[0][1]):
          if(y > self.topleft[1][0] and y < self.topleft[1][1]):
              print("In top left")
        # Check if the mouse click is in the top middle box
        if(x > self.topmiddle[0][0] and x < self.topmiddle[0][1]):
          if(y > self.topmiddle[1][0] and y < self.topmiddle[1][1]):
              print("In top middle")


Window().mainloop()
```

There are many other ways to do this but this should be enough to get you started.

As you can seen in my example, each box has two defining points. To draw an x in that box, just draw one of the lines from on of those points to the other and then draw the other line perpendicular to that. It shouldn’t be too hard. To draw a point in the center just draw it on the center point of the two defining x coordinates of the box.

Comment: This is very helpful, but then how do i  display an x or point onto the  top left box etc.

Comment: This is very helpful, but then how do i  display an x or point onto the  top left box etc.

Comment: I updated my answer. Honestly I would just do some research into some basic geometry and that should cover most of what you’re trying to do. Once you’ve got the basics figured out then you can leverage python to make it more efficient and less repetitive.

Comment: Great! Then if this answer successfully answered your question it would be beneficial to future viewers if you mark it as correct.